# Bash: Batch Resize Images

Tags: bash

I'm working on a Bash script that will take an array of directories, iterate through it, create a directory named "processed" inside each directory, and run a command on each file within the directory. Here's my code (read the comment in the code to see what I'm stuck on). Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash

command -v convert >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
    echo >&2 "Convert is not installed. Aborting.";
    exit 1;
}

declare -a directories_to_process=(
    "$HOME/Desktop/Album 1"
    "$HOME/Desktop/Album 2"
    "$HOME/Desktop/Album 3"
);

for directory in "${directories_to_process[@]}"
do
    if [ -d "$directory" ]; then
        if [ ! -d "$directory/processed" ]; then
            mkdir "$directory/processed"
        fi

        # Insert code to run the following command on each file in $directory:
        #
        # convert $directory/$filename -resize 108x108^ -gravity center -extent 108x108 $directory/processed/$filename
    fi
done
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the working script:

```
#!/bin/bash

command -v convert >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
    echo >&2 "Convert is not installed. Aborting.";
    exit 1;
}

directories_to_process=(
    "$HOME/Desktop/Album 1"
    "$HOME/Desktop/Album 2"
    "$HOME/Desktop/Album 3"
);

for directory in "${directories_to_process[@]}"
do
    [[ -d $directory ]] || continue

    mkdir -p "$directory/processed"

    for infile in "$directory"/*.jpg
    do
        outfile="$directory/processed/${infile##*/}"
        convert "$infile" \
                -resize '108x108^' \
                -gravity center \
                -extent 108x108 \
                "$outfile"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in the commented-out area:

```
for infile in "$directory"/*; do
  outfile="$directory/processed/${infile##*/}"
  convert "$infile" \
      -resize '108x108^' \
      -gravity center \
      -extent 108x108 \
      "$outfile"
done
```

A few other notes:

- Instead of nesting a great deal of logic inside of `if [ -d "$directory" ]`, consider putting `[[ -d $directory ]] || continue` at the top of the loop to reduce the nesting depth. (Unlike `[ ]`, quoting is not needed inside `[[ ]]` in this case).
- Instead of testing `[ ! -d "$directory/processed" ]` and using that to decide whether to create the directory, consider unconditionally running `mkdir -p "$directory/processed"`, which will simply exit with a successful status if the directory already exists.
- Consider replacing `command -v convert` with `type convert`, which is somewhat better known than the `command -v` syntax but will have the same effect.
- You don't need the `declare -a` when declaring an array variable outside of a function; simply `directories_to_process=( ... )` will work.

Comment: Quoting the whole glob won't work. Change it to `for infile in "$directory"/*; do`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Ugh -- I know better than that. Thank you for the catch.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That works! Thank you very much for not only answering my question, but providing tips for improvement. You're awesome! See my question for the final script I used. I stuck with `command -v` because, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/937084), `command`'s exit status is well defined by POSIX, so that one is probably the safest to use.

Comment: Note: if you use this as a standalone script, remember to create `processed` first, or you get unhelpful errors.